# Add date before entry title in Twenty Twelve

Tags: php, functions, theme-twenty-twelve

How do I add the date before the entry title in Twenty Twelve with just functions.php?

Right now I have to add and modify many files in the child theme such as content.php, content-aside.php, content-image.php, content-link.php, content-quote.php, content-status.php.

Is there a way to do it with filters? I tried to put it in the_content but the date displays below the title.

Answer (score 1):

Base on @Tunji answer.
You can add some conditions to the function to detect home-page, feeds...

```
function display_extra_title( $title, $id = null ) {

    $date = the_date('', '', '', false);

    if(is_home()){
        $title = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
        return $date . $title;
    }
    else{
        return $date . $title;
    }

}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'display_extra_title', 10, 2 );
```

In order to properly return `the_date` and not echoing it, you must set the last parameter to false. See more details [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date)

If you don't want to display the date in the menu widget... You can surround `$date` in a span and add css to not display it when it's the menu, sidebar...

```
$title = '<span class="title_date">'.$date.'</span> '.$title;
```

In the css (adjust and add all what you need:

```
.sidebar .title_date{ display:none;}
```

Comment: Thanks. 

Few things I see: 

The first post doesn't display the date. 

The post heading is replaced by the date and title of my site. 

The date needs to be a different div. 

Menu and sidebar items also display the title of my site (maybe because they too get replaced). 

How do I solve all of these?

Comment: I edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `the_title` filter. Example below.

```
function display_extra_title( $title, $id = null ) {

    $date = the_date();

    return $date . $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'display_extra_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Doesn't work: For home page, it just displays one date.